# Decimal Rounding Problem

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal

the following is my property where if we enter 45 then it appends 45.00 but then again it results in 45 because the value is converted from string. So what is the easiest way i can achieve this goal. Where if they enter 45 then it would result 45.00 in the value field;

```
 public decimal Length
    {
        get { if (this is Detail) 
           return ((this as Detail).Length.ToString() == string.Empty)
            ? 0 : (this as Detail).Length; else return 0; }
        set
        {
            if (this is Detail)
            {
                string val = string.Empty;

                if (!value.ToString().Contains("."))
                {
                    val = string.Format("{0}{1}", value.ToString(), ".00");
                    value =Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(val), 2);
                }
                else
                    value = Math.Round(value, 2);
                (this as Detail).Length = (value.ToString().Trim() == 
                string.Empty) ? 0 : value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is your property checking what `this` is? Seems like you have a broader issue with your level of abstraction.

Comment: this is in the datalayer and its winforms textbox bindings original property is comming from Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val = string.Format("{0:0.00}", value);
```

Comment: @DOTNETBEE - What is the goal of the `Length` property?  Do you want the whole number length, the decimal length, the entire length?  For example, if you 'set' `Length` to 35.12632, what do you want the value to be when you attempt to 'get' `Length`?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the property setter. You need to specify the string format in your GUI to round the numbers.

Also `if (this is PersonalDetail)` is a massive design flaw. Override the Length property in the PersonalDetail class instead. (not sure what the intent is with this property)

Comment: Entity Framewok Class for Property is extended as Partial Class which contains PersonalDetail as sub reference so its this is PersonalDetail.

Comment: Entity Framewok Class for Property is extended as partial class ? sub reference ? Don't quite understand

Comment: Designer is someone else who left i am just fixing bugs dont know i am also confused with the design...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 45m and 45.00m are the same thing, and since this is a decimal, it will always display "45" instead of "45.00" unless you use a string formatter every time you try to output it.

You could always make another property that does output what you want, such as:

```
public decimal Length { get; set; }

public string FormattedLength
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("{0:0.00}", this.Length);
    }
}
```

On a side note I don't like this, but I believe it gets you more or less what you are looking for.

Comment: Nope Not the right one because this are all bounded to text boxes it appears in textbox as 45.00 if we enter 45 but at the time of saving when i step through the code i am seeing that it turned to 45 again.

Comment: Thats because you will never see 45.00 when inspecting the Decimal directly.  Decimal, while precise, does not keep track of how many digits are significant, and treats 45m, 45.0m and 45.00m as being equal, and will always display as the simplest form possible (while a Decimal).